# Input/output error when attempting to mount a Windows NFS share

Tags: linux, windows-server-2012, nfs, network-share

I created the Windows Server 2012 share using:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> nfsshare testshare2=C:\testshare2 -o anon=yes anonuid=0 anongid=0 rw=uuu.uuu.uuu.uuu
testshare2 was shared successfully
```

Where *uuu.uuu.uuu.uuu* is the IP of my Ubuntu system.

Next, from the Ubuntu machine I mounted the Windows NFS share as follows:

```
sudo mount -t nfs xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/testshare2 /mnt/testshare2
```

Where *xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx* is the IP of the Windows Server 2012 machine.

No errors are shown when mounting, but when I `ls` the mounted directory, the following appears:

`ls: cannot open directory /mnt/testshare2/: Input/output error`

I'm not showing any errors in Ubuntu's syslog.

Here are properties of the share in Server 2012:
[image]

**Edit 1**:  I get the same input/output error when attempting to mount the Server 2012 NFS share from a RHEL7 machine.  Mount works fine I just can't ls directory or touch files.

**Edit 2**: In Server 2012, the NFS log shows a successful mount to both Ubuntu and RHEL machines.

Answer (score 5):

This is solved.  On **Server 2012**:

1. Opened `Server Manager -> Shares`
2. Removed the existing share
3. Deleted the previously shared folder
4. Started a new share using the `New Share Wizard`
   [image]
5. Selected `NFS Share - Quick` then clicked Next.
   [image]
6. Selected a new folder to share in `Type a custom path` then clicked
   Next.
   [image]
7. Confirmed `Share name`, `local path` and `remote paths` then clicked
   Next.
   [image]
8. On the Authentication window, I selected `No server authentication
   (AUTH_SYS)`, then selected `Enable unmapped user access by UID/GID`
   and made sure the `Allow unmapped user acess by UID/GID` radio
   button was selected.  Then clicked Next.
   [image]
9. On the Share Permissions window, I clicked `Add`.
10. An `Add Permissions` window popped up.  Here, next to `Host`, I
    entered the IP of the remote Linux computer that would be mounting,
    left `Language encoding` to `ANSI`, and set `Share permissions` to
    `Read/Write`.  I then clicked `Add` at the bottom which closed the
    `Add Permissions` window.
    [image]
11. On the Share Permissions window I confirmed settings entered in the
    previous step, then clicked Next.
    [image]
12. On the Specify Permissions window, I clicked Next without making
    changes.
    [image]
13. I confirmed settings on the `Confirm selections` window then clicked
    the `Create` button.
    [image]

---

Then from my **RHEL7** system I issued:

```
mount -t nfs sss.sss.sss.sss:/somedata /mnt/somedata/
```

Where `sss.sss.sss.sss` is the IP of the Server 2012 system.

From the **RHEL7** machine, I confirmed write access by issuing

```
date >> /mnt/somedata/date.txt
```

Then checked that the file existed from **Server 2012**.

Answer (score 1):

When creating an NFS share from Windows Server 2016, the above instructions helped alot.  One important piece is to also install the File Server Resource Manager role.  Prior to that I only got input/output error and linux reported mount as nfs version 3.  Afterward, linux reported nfs version 4.1 and the mount worked.

[image]